# Multitask learning main assumptions

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, mathematical-statistics

Multitask learning (ML) is a branch of transfer learning typically used in the machine learning society. In ML people utilize the similarities between units to improve accuracy of prediction etc...

The units are typically Independent, ex: car batteries, we believe that batteries from different cars might behave differently however they have some commonalities, thus if we model them together using ML we might get better results.

This idea seems common in machine learning, however, I believe also many statistical models utilize such approach , where they propose a common structure to model somehow different units. What are some statistics tool that use a similar ideology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A statistical approach that tries to tackle the problem of transfer learning, where the train and test set follow different distributions, is importance sampling.

Importance sampling is a general technique for estimating properties of a particular distribution, while only having samples generated from a different distribution than the distribution of interest. So weighting the instances of the train set in a way that the distribution of the train set will be close or will match the distribution of the test set is one of the most popular approaches of transfer learning.